# How to set the Active class lists to be first in ordered lists

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-lists

I have a number of lists out of which few lists are with **active** class.
I want the appearance in such a way that:
the lists having active class should list first in order and rest with no active class.

In the following snippet, I have lists **A, B, C, D, E, F**, list **D** and **F** should appear first in order like: **D, F, A, B, C, E**.

```css
li.slide.active{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sliderscroll">
  <li class="slide">
    List A
  </li>
  <li class="slide">
    List B
  </li>
  <li class="slide">
    List C
  </li>
  <li class="slide active">
    List D
  </li>
  <li class="slide">
    List E
  </li>
  <li class="slide active">
    List F
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How have you attempted to solve this, what went wrong? In what way? Please read the "*[ask]*" guidance to see what we expect of questions posted on the site, and then [edit] your question with improvements and further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are prepared/allowed to use *flexbox*, you can simply use `order` to change the position of *flexbox items*.

Reference: [MDN: Ordering flex items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
li {
    order: 1; /* place out of document order */
    /* the higher the number, the lower in the list */
}

li.slide.active {
    color: red;
    order: 0; /* place at top of list (above 'order 1') */
}
```

```html
<h3>With .active class</h3>
<ul class="sliderscroll">
    <li class="slide">
        List A
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        List B
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        List C
    </li>
    <li class="slide active">
        List D
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        List E
    </li>
    <li class="slide active">
        List F
    </li>
</ul>

<h3>No .active class</h3>
<ul class="sliderscroll">
    <li class="slide">
        List A
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        List B
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        List C
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        List D
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        List E
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        List F
    </li>
</ul>
```